# How to generate the same graphql query with different fields

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using `graphql-tag` so i'm going to use that syntax.

Lets say I have this query:

```
const query = gql`
 query user(id: String) {
  user(id: $id) {
   id
  }
 }
`
```

Whats the best patten to reuse that same query document node if on a different call I want the fields `username` and `email` in addition to `id` without having to rewrite the entire query again like:

```
const query = gql`
 query user(id: String) {
  user(id: $id) {
   id
   username
   email
  }
 }
`
```

I'm using `react-apollo` on the frontend if that makes things anymore interesting.

Edit:

Just to clarify... something like this

```
const userIdFrag = gql`
  fragment UserId on User {
    id
  }
`

const fullUserFrag = gql`
  fragment FullUser on User {
    id
    username
    email
  }
`

const generateQuery = (documentNode) => {
  return gql`
   query user(id: String) {
      user(id: $id) {
       ...documentNode
      }
     }
     ${documentNode}
  `
}

const idQuery = generateQuery(userIdFrag);
const fullUserQuery = generateQuery(fullUserFrag);
```

(The above does work but give me errors from graphql in the console, which leads me to believe this is not something I should be doing)

Comment: You can check out fragments - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments.html, although you'll still need to define the query 2 times

Comment: Yeah I know about fragments, I was wondering if there was a better way out there that didn't invlove writing the query signature every time

Comment: What are excalty the errors that you're getting?

Comment: @ric0 The error basically says "documentNode is not used in the graphql query", even though the ${documentNode} fragment is getting added to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment the following should work:

```
const generateQuery = (documentNode, fragment) => {
  return gql`
   query user(id: String) {
      user(id: $id) {
       ...${fragment}
      }
     }
     ${documentNode}
  `
}

const idQuery = generateQuery(userIdFrag, 'UserId');
const fullUserQuery = generateQuery(fullUserFrag, 'FullUser');
```

Basically the fragment name used is the actual one that needs to be spread while the whole documentNode object is put at the end, after query's closing bracket

Comment: This worked perfectly, It makes a lot more sense now that I see it written out. One change I might make is you can actually get the name of the frag from the documentNode at.... `node.definitions[0].name.value`

Comment: Yeah, sure. I did not think about that, it's more efficient your way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not the very expert on the topic, but here is what I have been able to find out. (if you see any mistakes in my assumptions, let me know).

I found [this article](https://blog.apollographql.com/5-benefits-of-static-graphql-queries-b7fa90b0b69a) that makes some good points against dynamically generating `gql` queries/mutations. It seems like you get some nice benefits with the static approach, although it's a bit more typing.

But, in case you do need to have dynamic fields, I haven't been able to find anything bad about using the `@skip` directive GraphQL provides. [Here the docs ref](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec--skip).

For the case of using it in `react-apollo` [they also have it in their docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/directives.html).

So, your code can end up looking something like this:

```
const query = gql`
 query user($id: String, $skipUserMeta: Boolean!) {
  user(id: $id) {
   id
   username @skip(if: $skipUserMeta)
   email @skip(if: $skipUserMeta)
  }
 }
`
```

You just pass the `skipUserMeta` as a variable alongside the `id` field.

NOTE: I actually found a video which talks about [the exact same approach here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eFgz06QPMs)